# Possible to recover ORF from TIFF created by Apple Photos?

Tags: photos.app, data-recovery

Using Apple Photos (as included in Ventura 13.1) for the first time, I told it to import a collection of raw photos off a SD card, and delete the originals.

This was a mistake: The originals were in Olympus Raw Format (ORF); they imported to TIFF. Some of the editing software I use isn't offering raw-aware denoise operations in this format.

TIFF is a flexible container format: It could be, I suppose, possible to recover the original file byte-for-byte, if Apple chose to prioritize storing everything necessary for this operation. But... did they?

Comment: TIFF is a lossless format, not a RAW one.  Your original . ORF  should be on the SD card.

Comment: I (stupidly) assumed the import process would preserve the original data and clicked the checkbox to delete the originals; they're not longer there. That said, TIFF is an extensible container format -- one can put arbitrary data inside it -- and in Apple Photos, the images say "RAW".

Comment: If you are planning to do post work, I highly suggest an app like Lightroom as it is much more attune to working with these files.  You also want to convert from RAW to DNG (digital negative) which is a better format for manipulating photos.

Comment: @Allan, ...better ORF than DNG in present circumstances: using the vendor's proprietary format means one can use the vendor's [proprietary tools](https://app.olympus-imaging.com/olympusworkspace/en/). I'm not willing to buy into Adobe's subscription model.

Comment: I'd probably be looking at Disk Drill or similar to try recover them off the SD card. You can't get the RAW back from a tiff; it's been de-mosaiced, can't unbake the cake. DNG has its uses, but only really if you're using Adobe right through. I can quite understand wanting the manufacturer's software over Camera RAW, which is just a guesswork attempt at reverse engineering the camera manufacturer's algorithms [& imnsho, makes a lousy job of it.] tbh, I don't let Apple's Photos structure anywhere near my 'real' photos, only ones off my phone.

Comment: You can use Image Capture to pull pictures off the SD [with or without delete] into any designated folder & it will not attempt to convert them.

Comment: *Late thought:* Right click the Photos library, Show Package Contents > Masters > [matching date] & see if they were actually dropped in there, untouched.

Comment: Recovering the originals with Disk Drill is the approach I eventually took.